# How does rate layer count affect my neuronal network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

HI i've created a simple neuronal network in java:
https://github.com/wutzebaer/Neuronal

It has only 3 neurons; input hidden output

When the input is > 0.7 output should be 1, otherwise 0

Question1: 
When i set my rate to 1 it seems to divergate fast, when i choose 0.1 it does not come to a result. Why is this, i thought a smaller rate whould just take longer.

Question2:
Why to i only get a 99% hit rate for such a simple problem? Is it not toal solveable by a neuronal network?

Question3:
the amount of neurons per layer does not seem to have much effect, but when i choose 2 or more layers the results are worse, even when learning for a long time. Why? Aren't more layers better?

Question4: 
is my calculus correct? I've compared my values to http://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/comment-page-1/#comment-17063 and they where correct for 1 hidden layer. But i don't know if i've abstracted it correctly for n layers

I've checked in my small project here:
https://github.com/wutzebaer/Neuronal

CODE

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class NeuronNetwork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NeuronNetwork();
    }

    final Integer layers = 2;
    final Integer hiddenNeuronPerLayer = 10;
    List<InputNeuron> inputNeurons = new ArrayList<InputNeuron>();
    List<OutputNeuron> outputNeurons = new ArrayList<OutputNeuron>();
    List<List<Neuron>> hiddenLayers = new ArrayList<List<Neuron>>();

    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public void train(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fillTraining();
            updateOutput();
            learn();
        }
    }

    public int test(int count) {
        int correct = 0;
        Double error = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fillTraining();
            updateOutput();
            Double calcTotalError = calcTotalError();
            error += Math.abs(calcTotalError);
            if (Math.abs(outputNeurons.get(0).desiredOutput - outputNeurons.get(0).output) < 0.1d) {
                correct++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println((error / (double) count) + " " + correct + " / " + count);
        return correct;
    }

    public NeuronNetwork() {

        System.out.println("staret");
        // add input neurons
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            inputNeurons.add(new InputNeuron(1d));
        }

        // add output neurons
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            outputNeurons.add(new OutputNeuron());
        }

        for (Integer layerIndex = 0; layerIndex < layers; layerIndex++) {
            ArrayList<Neuron> currentHiddenlayer = new ArrayList<Neuron>();
            // add input connections
            for (Integer hiddenNeuronInLayerIndex = 0; hiddenNeuronInLayerIndex < hiddenNeuronPerLayer; hiddenNeuronInLayerIndex++) {
                Neuron hiddenNeuron = new Neuron();
                // add first layer
                if (layerIndex == 0) {
                    for (Neuron input : inputNeurons) {
                        hiddenNeuron.addInput(input);
                    }
                }
                // add inner layers
                else {
                    for (Neuron input : hiddenLayers.get(layerIndex - 1)) {
                        hiddenNeuron.addInput(input);
                    }
                }
                currentHiddenlayer.add(hiddenNeuron);
            }
            hiddenLayers.add(currentHiddenlayer);
        }

        // add all neurons of last hidden layer to each input neuron
        for (Neuron out : outputNeurons) {
            for (Neuron hidden : hiddenLayers.get(hiddenLayers.size() - 1)) {
                out.addInput(hidden);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            train(100000);
            if (test(1000) == 1000) {
                test(10000);
                break;
            }
        }

        inputNeurons.get(0).output = 0.0d;

        updateOutput();

        System.out.println("OUTPUT " + outputNeurons.get(0).output);

    }

    public void fillTraining() {
        for (InputNeuron input : inputNeurons) {
            input.output = r.nextDouble();
        }

        if (inputNeurons.get(0).output > 0.7d) {
            outputNeurons.get(0).desiredOutput = 1d;
        } else {
            outputNeurons.get(0).desiredOutput = 0d;
        }

    }

    public Double calcTotalError() {
        Double error = 0d;
        for (OutputNeuron out : outputNeurons) {
            error += Math.pow(out.desiredOutput - out.output, 2);
        }
        error *= 0.5d;
        return error;
    }

    public void updateOutput() {
        for (List<Neuron> layer : hiddenLayers) {
            for (Neuron n : layer) {
                n.updateOutput();
            }
        }
        for (OutputNeuron n : outputNeurons) {
            n.updateOutput();
        }
    }

    public void learn() {
        for (List<Neuron> layer : hiddenLayers) {
            for (Neuron n : layer) {
                n.calcNewW();
            }
        }
        for (OutputNeuron n : outputNeurons) {
            n.calcNewW();
        }
        for (List<Neuron> layer : hiddenLayers) {
            for (Neuron n : layer) {
                n.applyNewW();
            }
        }
        for (OutputNeuron n : outputNeurons) {
            n.applyNewW();
        }
    }

}

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;

public class Neuron {
    public static Double rate = 1d;
    public HashSet<Neuron> inputs = new HashSet<Neuron>();
    public HashSet<Neuron> outputs = new HashSet<Neuron>();
    public HashMap<Neuron, Double> weights = new HashMap<Neuron, Double>();
    public HashMap<Neuron, Double> newWeights = new HashMap<Neuron, Double>();
    public Double bias = 0d;
    public Double output = 0d;
    static Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    /**
     * add input with default weight of 0.5
     * 
     * @param i
     */
    public void addInput(Neuron i) {
        addInput(i, r.nextDouble() * 0.1d);
    }

    public void addInput(Neuron i, Double weight) {
        inputs.add(i);
        weights.put(i, weight);
        i.outputs.add(this);
    }

    public void updateOutput() {
        Double sum = bias;
        for (Neuron input : inputs) {
            sum += input.output * weights.get(input);
        }
        output = logistic(sum);
    }

    public static Double logistic(Double sum) {
        return 1d / (1d + Math.exp(-sum));
    }

    protected void calcNewW() {

        // wie wirkt sich der gesamtinput der neurone auf den output der neurone aus?
        // => output der neurone * (1-output der neurone)
        Double wert2 = wieWirktSichDerInputAufDenOutputAus();

        // wie wirkt sich der output der neurone auf den total error aus?
        Double wert3 = wieWirktSichDerOutputAufDenTotalErrorAus();

        for (Entry<Neuron, Double> connection : weights.entrySet()) {
            Neuron input = connection.getKey();
            Double weight = connection.getValue();

            // wie wirkt sich das w auf den input der neurone aus?
            // => output der quellneurone
            Double wert1 = input.output;

            Double result = wert1 * wert2 * wert3;
            newWeights.put(input, weight - rate * result);
        }

        bias -= wert3 * rate;

    }

    protected Double wieWirktSichDerOutputAufDenTotalErrorAus() {
        // => ist zunächst die summe für alle zielneuronen => wie wirkt dich der output auf den fehler der zielneurone aus
        Double wert3 = 0d;
        for (Neuron out : outputs) {
            // ==> wie wirkt sich der netzinput der nächsten neurone auf den fehlerwert der nächsten neurone aus
            // 1. wie wirkt sich der input auf den output aus => output der neurone * (1-output der neurone)
            Double wert3_a_a = out.wieWirktSichDerInputAufDenOutputAus();
            // 2. wie wirkt sich der output auf den fehler aus
            Double wert3_a_b = out.wieWirktSichDerOutputAufDenTotalErrorAus();
            // => rekursoin bis zur out neurone, und dort
            // -(EXPECTED-OUTPUT)

            // ==mal

            // ==> wie wirkt sich der output der neurone auf dern input der nächsten neurone aus => das aktuelle w
            Double wert3_b = out.weights.get(this);

            wert3 += wert3_a_a * wert3_a_b * wert3_b;

        }
        return wert3;
    }

    private double wieWirktSichDerInputAufDenOutputAus() {
        return output * (1d - output);
    }

    public void applyNewW() {
        weights = newWeights;

    }

}

public class InputNeuron extends Neuron {
    public InputNeuron(Double output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
}

public class OutputNeuron extends Neuron {
    public Double desiredOutput = 1d;

    protected Double wieWirktSichDerOutputAufDenTotalErrorAus() {
        return -(desiredOutput - output);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post all necessary information in the question itself. The other questions might be okay (maybe, depending on whether these problems are from problems in your code or things that generally happen), but the 4th one definitely isn't answerable without following the links (and verification-type questions usually aren't accepted here). We usually prefer 1 question per ... question - you can only accept 1 answer, and one person might not answer all these correctly or sufficiently.

Comment: A lot of your code is in German...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question1: When i set my rate to 1 it seems to divergate fast, when i choose 0.1 it does not come to a result. Why is this, i thought a smaller rate whould just take longer.

A smaller rate will take longer, but it's hard to say how much longer. Maybe you're not running enough iterations.

If `1` is too large and `0.1` too small, try `0.2, 0.3, ...` until you find something suitable, and try also changing your number of iterations.

You can also try adding [momentum](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#sgd) to your learning.

> Question2: Why to i only get a 99% hit rate for such a simple problem? Is it not toal solveable by a neuronal network?

You might be suffering from [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). With what data are you training your net, and what are you testing on?

`99%` isn't bad, but you can probably get it to perfect with regularization ([weight decay](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/difference-between-neural-net-weight-decay-and-learning-rate) for example), using a smaller network (fewer hidden units) or using more training data. Training data should be very easy to generate in your case.

> Question3: the amount of neurons per layer does not seem to have much effect, but when i choose 2 or more layers the results are worse, even when learning for a long time. Why? Aren't more layers better?

Like you said, your problem is very simple. More layers will lead to a more complex network, which will overfit your simple data. The bigger network, being more powerful, will simply memorize your training data, and it will perform poorly on the test data.

Other things can also go wrong with a deeper network, such as vanishing gradients and the weights getting too large. Don't use deep networks for such simple problems. Bigger is not always better.

Comment: My take on question 2 was a bit different. The problem is a simple `if/else` and a neural network is not really a suitable approach to this problem because it is only an approximator. It's hundreds of lines of unnecessary code that will serve to exasperate problems with a hexadecimal system; I'm not sure it could ever work as well as `if/else` ...

Comment: @roganjosh that's true, but so is xor for example, and a neural network can compute the xor of two bits. It should be able to get perfect accuracy for a threshold problem. For this problem, the neural network just needs to apply the sigmoid function to `input - 0.7`. That should be very easy to learn. Probably the easiest with just 1 input neuron and 1 output, so logistic regression. But a few more should also work.